# NTP Traffic, but NTP not installed

Tags: linux-networking, ntp, opnsense

I have recently started with OPNSense and have limited outgoing traffic to HTTP/s, SSH ports. When analyzing my blocked traffic i found sporadic outgoing NTP-Requests from my local Linux machine.

I am not very familiar with NTP.
I am now wondering a few things.

1. The source port is always different. Is this normal behavior/ caused by the firewall block?

   ```
   192.168.1.101:52936
   192.168.1.101:54299
   192.168.1.101:45992
   ...
   ```
2. I actually don't have NTP installed. So i don't quite understand why i even have NTP traffic?

Comment: Yes, source port is a random high-port, destination port is 123. Are you sure you dont have a NTP-client? Most distros have one preinstalled...

Comment: Oh okay good to know. I have checked for both the ntp and openntpd package (Arch). So unless it is some really strange NTP-client that came as a dependency, i shouldn't really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Linux distros ship with an NTP client enabled by default.  Check your system for `chrony` or `systemd-timesyncd`.  The latter is the default on most `systemd`-enabled distributions.

Comment: Right, i actually have a systemd-timesyncd service running. Thanks for the answer! :)